# Reference missing. 2 projects in one solution.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

For a school assignment, i need to create a WPF application, and ASP.net MCV application. They need to share the same DB and model classes.

I have created the WPF part, and are now trying to use the model classes (which are placed in the WPF project) in the ASP.net project. For now, all im trying to do is write a customer name out on a ASP.net view. But there is something wrong with the connection.

This i have done so far:

- I have copied the connectionstring from the app.config, to the web.config
- In the web project, i have put a reference to the WPF project.

What else do i need to create a proper connection between the two projects? I can put "using" directives in the ASP.net files without errors.

Error description: CS0246. The type or namespace "MyWPFProject" was not found (missing using-directive or assemply reference)?

[image]

Comment: Personally I would not reference the WPF app in the MVC website, make the Model/DB classes there own project and reference that in both the WPF and MVC app, otherwise you are going to have to add all the dependencies for WPF to the MVC website.

Comment: Thank you, i will do that. What do you mean by dependencies exactly?